# "Two people got hurt and five people died in the tragedy" 

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, meaning-in-context

Can you say so? In other words, are deaths counted among people that got hurt?

Does it make a difference if you say:

> Two people were injured and five people died in the tragedy.

Let's imagine someone stabbed a knife into someone else. Then the victim is injured and then let's assume he dies afterwards. Does the victim need to be counted both as injured and killed? Then let's assume someone died immediately because of a heart attack or something. Does that count as injured?

Comment: As an aside, the word "tragedy" is over-used. Blame the inflation of superlatives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the context.  In early news reporting, where the aims these days seem to be speed and sensationalism rather than factual accuracy, the focus is likely to be on the number of deaths.  Thus you’ll see a headline like:

> Five killed in tragedy

Maybe expanded in an article as:

> Five people died and two others were injured in the tragedy

But in a formal investigation report of the incident you’re more likely to read:

> Injuries: 7 (5 fatal, 2 serious)

Comment: Which gives the favorite "news quiz" quote - "Police say 5 people were killed in the accident but nobody was seriously hurt"

Comment: or the (apocryphal?) Victorian quote "The woman was bludgeoned and left for dead.  It is unclear whether she was assaulted."

Answer (score 5):

"Injuries" and "deaths" are disjoint groups usually, though you may sometimes speak of a "fatal injury" (an injury that later leads to death).

They may both be classified as **`casualties`** of an incident.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, deaths are deaths and injuries are injuries, so the dead are not counted as injured.

And I'd say "injured" instead of "got hurt".  "Got hurt" makes me think of kids, of children.  "Mommy, I got hurt!" sort of thing.  Not to mention that "got hurt" can mean something else, as in "That remark really hurt my feelings!".

The victim of a stabbing (btw, "someone stabbed someone else with a knife", "to stab a knife into someone", while (I think) grammatically correct, just sounds weird) would count as injured.  Until he dies (if he does so).  Then he counts as dead.

Comment: I would not say "my feelings got hurt from that remark," though.

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, if I hear regarding a fracas that so-and-so "got hurt" (as opposed "was hurt"), I'm much more likely to assume he was an active participant rather than an innnocent bystander caught up in the violence.